# Reading certain number of elements from File in Java

Tags: java, file, io

I have a text file with few numbers in a line ;

10 20 30 40 50

My motto is to read 3 numbers at a time and perform some operation on it. 
Please help me to learn best ways to do this job.

I need to work on numbers in this fashion,

10 20 30

20 30 40

30 40 50 .....

If my text file has a line with 100000 numbers is it suggestable to load the entire file in memory and keep traversing and performing operations or is it good to copy the entire line in an array and perform operations on it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
    int a, b, c;

    // try with resources, scanner will be closed when we are done.
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {
        // get the first three ints.
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();
        c = scan.nextInt();
        doSomething(a, b, c);
        // while there are more
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = scan.nextInt();
            doSomething(a, b, c);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | NoSuchElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will read one number at a time, and perform some operation in between each read.

If you want to read all the numbers before performing operation, you can use an array list.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // try with, scanner will be closed when we are done.
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {
        // while there are more
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            list.add(scan.nextInt());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | NoSuchElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then you can iterate through them.

```
    for (int i : list) {

    }
```

Using an `IntBuffer` instead of `ArrayList` would work if you know how many numbers there were.

For only 100000 values it probably doesn't make much difference if you load them as you need them or load them all first. If your operation takes a long time it might be better to load them all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you want. Load all the numbers to the memory will take more time, but operations with the numbers in memory will be faster. If you don't want to allocate a "big" portion of your memory to hold all the numbers you can read the file and at the same time do the operation. Although, it will not make much difference, since the file just hold numbers and its size won't be to big.

Below is a code sample that achieves what you want.

**Full Code**

```
public static void main (String args[]){

    //Scanner will read your file
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // tmpInts will old the tmp values that are read
    int [] tmpInts = new int[3];
    // Holds a controller to know if we can do the operation
    int i = 0;

    while(scanner.hasNextInt()){

        // Do the operation only when tmpInts has 3 numbers inside it
        if(i > 2){

            System.out.println("Read: ["+tmpInts[0] +" "+ tmpInts[1] +" "+ tmpInts[2]+"] Sum: "+(tmpInts[0] + tmpInts[1] + tmpInts[2]));
            shiftInts(tmpInts);

            tmpInts[2] = scanner.nextInt(); // Read next number

        } else {
            tmpInts[i] = scanner.nextInt(); // Read next number
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Check if there are at least 3 numbers in the file
    // If not, don't do the operation
    // If yes, this is the last operation call to handle the last state of tmpInts array
    if(!isEmpty(tmpInts))
        System.out.println("Read: ["+tmpInts[0] +" "+ tmpInts[1] +" "+ tmpInts[2]+"] Sum: "+(tmpInts[0] + tmpInts[1] + tmpInts[2]));

    scanner.close(); // IMPORTANT! Don't forget to close your scanner

}

// Shift numbers one index left to put a third one in the last index of the array after
public static void shiftInts(int[] tmpInts) {
    tmpInts[0] = tmpInts[1];
    tmpInts[1] = tmpInts[2];
}

// Check if array is full. If it is not it means that your file doesn't have at least 3 numbers. i choosed 0 as default value in array, you can choose another one that won't appear in your file
public static boolean isEmpty(int[] tmpInts) {
    for(int i: tmpInts){
        if(i == 0){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I took line as a String and converted into array of integers to load all numbers into the memory. We can do required operations on integer array by iteration.

Below is the sample code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "temp1.txt";
    String line;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] inputNumbers = line.split(",");
            int numbers[] = new int[inputNumbers.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < inputNumbers.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputNumbers[i]);
                                }
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length - 2; j++) {
                int sum = numbers[j] + numbers[j + 1] + numbers[j + 2];
                System.out.println(sum);
            }


        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();


    } catch (IOException ex) {


        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achive and what your question is. Please make it more clear